# \06 is converted to a character that looks like a spade

Tags: python, character-encoding

The code below is from a python script currently being developed. The script errors out due to an invalid filename.

```
saveInPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\AV_FILES\06_School\Python205\ProjectNov2014\CODE_CLEAN\NotQuiteBackUP"    
lccSysProcCons = SystemProcessControls()   
dateTimeNow = lccSysProcCons.getDateTimeNow()  
name = "Rejected Tracks List %s" % str(dateTimeNow)  
saveAsName = saveInPath + "\\" + name + ".txt"  
print saveAsName
```

The saveAsName variable appears to invalidate the script. When printed out it shows up as:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\AV_FILES♠_School\Python205\ProjectNov2014\CODE_CLEAN\NotQuiteBackUP\Rejected Tracks List 2014-12-27 15:31:07.txt
```

NOTICE the spade character [♠] in place of [\06]. Why is this? This will probably be resolved by changing the folder name. I just want to know why this happens.

Comment: [Backslashes are used to denote escape sequences unless the string literal is prefixed with `r`.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: Windows [CP437](http://czyborra.com/charsets/codepages.html) has a ♠︎ (Unicode U+2660 BLACK SPADE SUIT) symbol at code point 6.

Comment: @gnat I didn't ask at Stack Overflow because I thought this was a question for programmers, I didn't know there was a difference =] http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow. Thanks for reposting!